# How to change Ubuntu installation path and all related things on Windows (WSL)?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So I installed Ubuntu on Windows from Store.

But I don't want it on my C disk, I don't have many space there.

I would like to move to another disk, I also would like to use external HDD

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779801/move-wsl-bash-on-windows-root-filesystem-to-another-hard-drive, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#how-can-i-back-up-my-wsl-distros-or-move-them-from-one-drive-to-another

Comment: @muru I guess, my question just sounds quite different from those questions, but yes, it should be the same